# Why comma, and other options associated with fractions are not active in the programmer view of default Windows 7 calculator?

Tags: windows-7, calculator

Notation system I set to decimal, but the options associated with decimals are inactive.

The problem is only in the programmer view (ALT + 3). In other views I can use the comma.

[image]

Does anyone know what causes the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Programmer's view the calculator will only handle integers, so there is no purpose to the decimal point

Comment: Good to know... @GypsySpellweaver thanks for the reply.